# how to delete all tags from shotwell

Tags: shotwell, metadata

i have been having this issue where some stock photos where imported into shotwell. Now that is not bad on its own but they brought with them hundreds of image tags.

[image]

I tried removing all the tags from the images but now I just have a bunch of empty tags. I want to be able to use the tags for sorting my photos but I can't with all of this garbage. is there a way to remove all tags without having to delete them one by one. I would assume that it is in some folder somewhere but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are stored at `$HOME/.shotwell/data/photo.db`

It is a database file and you can use something like [sqlitebrowser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) to explore that database. You can use a DELETE to delete records.